# Opening Web Browser click in default browser

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently I am building a windows form app using c#. I have a web browser control on my form that displays a google ad. When clicked the webpage is displayed within the little 300x300 web browser control on the form. Is there a way for me to launch the default browser when the ad is clicked instead?

Thanks.

Edit: I figured out I can do so open the default browser by using Process.Start("url here"); but the browser windows is opening upon app load.

Edit Adding Code:
Form.cs

```
    private void AdPanelNavigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        if (e.Url != null ) Process.Start(e.Url.ToString());
    }
```

Form.Designer.cs

```
this.AdPanel.Navigating += new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(AdPanelNavigating);
```

Comment: could you add your code?

Comment: I added additional information up top

Comment: why you don't use webbrowsercontrol?

Comment: I am using web browser control

Comment: with Process.Start("url here"); you can not handel events instead of this use webbrowser.navigate("url") after webpage completed you can call every event if you add a part of your code i can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Navigating event handler:

```
webBrowser1.Navigating += new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(WebBrowser_Navigating);

void WebBrowser_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e) {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Process.Start(e.Url);
    }
```

It will open default browser instead of opening this url inside webbrowser.

Comment: This works although it opens the browser page during the initial load. I would like to not open the browser during the initial load but only when the ad is clicked.